# Power Consumptions of GFCI Outlets and GFCI Breakers

Tags: protection

Due to my applications, I need to know the ballpark power consumption of the internal circuit of a GFCI receptacle and GFCI breaker. Has anyone measured them? Could they reach above 5w or 7w?

Comment: ballpark zero watts. (not including resistive losses, or diruing tripping)

Comment: I was talking about the internal circuit. The chip, etc. uses power, how can it be zero watts?

Comment: it's  closer to zero than it is to one.

Comment: the SCR will draw high power to trip the Relay but not the sensor electronics

Comment: how high the power the SCR can draw?

Comment: What research have you done, what have you found? So people don’t waste effort repeating what you have already...

Comment: im googling at net. It's only hearsay. Here someone mentioned 7 watts. But others didn't believe. So I don't know. https://www.garagejournal.com/forum/showthread.php?t=209624&showall=1 Has someone among you read one which is accurate? I don't know if it is 0.5watt or 5watt or 7watt.

Answer (score 5):

This one uses upto 120mW (the data sheet says 500uA - at 240V that's 120mW)

http://www.chip-memory.com/pdf/4-1-2-1b.pdf

This one with self test has two 75K resistors in series with the supply
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN41501-D.pdf
[image]

so that would be max 1.6W at 240v or 0.4W at 120V

Comment: That's an old design without the auto-monitoring self test. How about a GFCI breaker with this latest feature, should it uses more power? Do you have any tear down of a GFCI breaker? If any GFCI outlet or GFCI breaker would consumed 5watt. Would it get hot? Someone told me it could be as much as 5watt.

Comment: @Jtl who was this "someone "? What is the evidence for the value they stated?

Comment: no evidence, he just told me. That is the exact reason I'm asking now to get hard data and facts.

Comment: @Jtl You didn't ask for "hard data and facts", you asked for **ballpark** values. You can't complain if that's exactly what you get.

Comment: your national electriocal code may well permit as much as 5W quiescent. that does not mean that manufacurers will design to use all of that.

Answer (score 2):

It takes approximately 0.85W in tripped state, or 0.98W in standard active mode, determined by direct measurement of a modern self-testing "faith Electric" GFCI outlet produced in China and purchased from Amazon.